# IsEditable on a combobox is not having an effect

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to make my `ComboBox` editable. My `Combobox` displays a list of countries, and I would like my users to be able to type in the country to search for it. However, in its current state, it doesn't do that. What have I done wrong?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbCountryList" Width="150" 
    IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
    IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    TextSearch.TextPath="CountryName"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding CountryMasterList,  Mode=TwoWay}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="CountryName" 
    SelectedValuePath="CountryID" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CountryObj, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
    Text="{Binding Path=CountryName,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to work like an auto-complete box? The purpose of editing in a ComboBox is to allow entry of a TextBox-like value that isn't already present in the list in addition to selecting from the available items (hence Combo).

Comment: Yes i am expecting like Auto-Complete Box.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx for an example of how you can implement this.